# Filters are not Working in grails3

Tags: grails, grails-3.1, grails-filters

I've `SecurityFilters.groovy` in my application, basically it used to handle every request and does the some logic accordingly..it was wrking perfectly in grails2.
but after migrating to grails3 that filter is not working.
I even tried registering in `resources.groovy` then also it's not intercepting.

Comment: Grails 3 introduced concept of interceptors as a replacement of filters. Though the support of filters are still there, they are marked as deprecated. You probably like to look at that.

Comment: You can have look here to understand [Filters in Grails 2 vs 3](https://causecode.com/blog/38/filters-in-grails-2x-vs-grails-3)